# Python Pandas apply value

Tags: pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I have a df with several columns: 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year' and 'value'. I've grouped by 'week' and 'hour' with 'value' looking for mean():

```
df_group = df.groupby(['week','hour']).value.mean().reset_index()
```

Now I want to apply that mean value as a separate column for each hour in each week. Any ideas? 
THanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if need add new column to original data:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['week','hour']).value.transform('mean')
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!